# Is it possible to create separate error pages for the backend and frontend in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I am currently working in the the project where I've public view i.e. front end and back end for admin purpose.

I want to display separate error page for back end and front end when 404 error is encountered.

Is it possible to do in laravel ?

or Can we make error pages based on namespaces as well ?

Currently I've error pages inside `/resources/views/errors/` directory.

Any suggestion are appreciated. If further information needed then feel free to ask.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a year old now, but just to build on this answer. I would suggest that the better approach is not to write that if statement in your `render` method, but rather pull down the `getHttpExceptionView()` method, and overwrite that.

(Add this code snippet into your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` - it overwrites what's there in the parent class)

```
/**
 * Get the view used to render HTTP exceptions.
 *
 * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface  $e
 * @return string
 */
protected function getHttpExceptionView(HttpExceptionInterface $e)
{
    $adminErrorView = "admin.errors.{$e->getStatusCode()}";

    if (Str::is('admin*', request()->path())) {
        if (view()->exists($adminErrorView)) {
            return $adminErrorView;
        }
    }

    return "errors::{$e->getStatusCode()}";
}
```

That way if your request path is from "admin" (or anything with admin in the path anywhere), it will go and get the custom error files which you can create in `views/admin/errors` - name them as you would for the frontend... by error status code (`404.blade.php`, `500.blade.php`, etc)

*(Edit: made a tweak to my code, so that even if the view doesn't exist yet, it will default back to the normal front-end error view)*

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best option.

You could separate views based on a current path in Exception Handler's `render()` method.

app/Exceptions/Handler.php:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
        if(str_is('/admin*', request()->path())){
            return response()->view('errors.backend.404', [], 404);
        } else {
            return response()->view('errors.frontend.404', [], 404);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```