# Use Laravel's default error pages as supposed to custom created ones

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I have implemented custom error pages in my Laravel project but now run in to a situation where I actually want to fallback on displaying the default ones. The application consists  of an admin area and 'front' area. I created the custom error pages for the front area but want to fall back on the default ones for the admin area.

The request comes in via the `app\Exceptions\Handler.php, render()` method which calls its parent `render()` method in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php`. I'm kind of stuck at the `convertExceptionToResponse()` method within this class which seems to be called in case of a custom template but not in case of a default template.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: so you want to use custom error pages for Front and default error pages for Admin area?

Comment: @HarshDoshi yes

Comment: For that you need to register custom exceptions and return custom views for each exception

Comment: Quick thought: You will need custom exception to bifurcate exceptions between enduser panel and admin panel. Then based on exception you can render different views.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to this post [Is it possible to create separate error pages for the backend and frontend in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071200/is-it-possible-to-create-separate-error-pages-for-the-backend-and-frontend-in-la)

What I did was copy the dafault error pages to the subfolder `/admin`, we probably will customize them in the future anyway.

```php
protected function getHttpExceptionView(HttpExceptionInterface $e)
{
    if (isAdminPage()) {
        return "errors.admin.{$e->getStatusCode()}";
    }

    return "errors::{$e->getStatusCode()}";
}
```